# How to subdivide a class in geom_points()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot bird measures using species as class, but I'd also like to split species into males and females, as if they were two different plotting columns. When I use box_plot()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeOUd.png), it automatically does that, but I can't do the same with geom_points()

Let's suppose "birds" is my dataset, `x=species`, `y=bill.length` and `color=sex`

How to split species in two columns using the class sex?

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide the code for your question: your input data, exactly what you tried, here you see the error etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The right call is to `geom_point()`, not `geom_points()`. Make sure you're using the right calls.

Comment: Some hints:  Maybe you want to assign sex to a color or shape (e.g. `aes(x=... , color=sex)`, or maybe you want to use `facet_grid(~sex)` to separate them into separate plots.

Comment: I'm using the following code: plot<-ggplot(birds,aes(x=species,y=bill.length,color=sex))+geom_point() 
But I get a graph with individuals colored by sex in the same column category (species). What I want is to offset one of the sexes in the same species column (also in the same graph) to avoid spatial overlap. I want something similar to the boxplot graph I posted but with points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

bird.plot<-ggplot(birds,aes(x=sex,y=bill.length,color=sex,alpha=.7))+geom_point()+facet_grid(~species)

[result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8hAP.jpg)